# Pull and push data from and into sql databases using Excel VBA without pasting the data in Excel sheets

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I want to use Excel vba to pull data from one database (server) and then push the same to another (local). However, I don't want to paste the data in any excel sheets during the process as this slows down the Excel a lot. How can I do this? Below is my work so far. I have highlighted where my code stops with error - Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

```
Sub get_data_temp()
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim server, port, id, pass As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    'get data from server (MS SQL based)
    strSQL = Range("query_1").Value
    server = Range("db_server").Value
    port = Range("db_port").Value
    id = Range("db_id").Value
    pass = Range("db_pass").Value

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    strConnection = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & server & "," & port & ";User ID=" & id & ";Password=" & pass & ";"
    cn.Open strConnection
    Set rs = cn.Execute("SET NOCOUNT ON;" & strSQL)

    'connect to ms access to import data
    Dim xcn As Object
    Dim xrs As Object
    Dim xdbpath As String
    Dim xstrConnection As String
    Dim xdb_name As String
    Dim xstrSQL As String

    ''''''''the code stops at the line below'''''''''''''
    xstrSQL = "insert into crm_main select * from " & rs
    ''''''''the code stops at the line above'''''''''''''

    xdb_name = "temp.accdb"
    xdbpath = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & xdb_name
    Set xcn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    xstrConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & dbpath
    xcn.Open xstrConnection
    xcn.Execute(xstrSQL)
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    xcn.Close
    Set xcn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: If it's an Access db, using excel seems odd.  Have you considered doing everything in Access?  In fact, if you can set up a linked table you might not need any programming code at all.

Comment: good point. if i am able to setup a linked table, can i then trigger refreshing of that table using excel vba? I want the interface to be in Excel because all the analysis will be done there.

Comment: i tried connecting the access db to server which worked out. however it only gives me option to import tables as they are. there are too many tables on the server and i have built a query that combines data from some of these tables. Ideally I would want that a table in access db is linked to the server through that custom query so that the data is downloaded pre-processed. how do you think this is possible?

Comment: I'm not sure how you connected access to the server, but the way I do it is to set up an ODBC datasource on Windows, and use it in Access to get external data.  That allows me to set up linked tables.

Comment: thanks! i was in progress of doing the same while the discussion is going on here. I am now able to link access db to the server and also have setup a "Pass Through" query to fetch data from server using custom query. However, this query asks for the dsn file and database password every time i run the query. I am working on automating this. let me know if you have any thoughts. thanks again!

Comment: found the solutions so far (lucky i am). setup a pass through query as i said before and then linked the dsn file in the query property sheet. source - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/303968 once i am done i will add a full solution to the original question